# how to keep logs in two index logstash configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

How to keep logs in more than one index in one raw_log and in another processed logs.

With my current configuration all logs goes to logstash-xxx index. Now i want to make some filter on login message and would like to put in different index. But all the matched log also should go to logstash-xxx index.

How can i achieve that.

Comment: Why don't using one index with two mode? processed and raw log ? It's a common use case if it satisfies your needs.

Comment: You can do that by parsing your logs with a grok plugin. By so doing, you will be able to create index depending on the type. Maybe I could be of addition help if you could share some of logs and explain better how you will like to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking to send audit-related messages to a new index, one that perhaps has separate retention policies. I know this pain.

There are a few ways to handle this.

In my opinion, the best way is to identify your audit-related items, tag them, and then use that tag in your outputs. Such as...

```
filter {
  if [path] =~ "auth.log$" {
    mutate {
      add_tags => [ "audit" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    logstash-index stuff
  }

  if "audit" in [tags] {
    elasticsearch {
      audit-index stuff
    }
  }
}
```

With this config, the events tagged `audit` will be placed into both the usual `logstash-` index, as well as your separate index.

Comment: Thanks alot it seems working. one more thing how to remove certain fields only for audit-index output ? ra_log which will go to usual logstash-xxx index will be having all fields.

Comment: @shamimakhtar Add a filter-block, put another `if` statement the same as the one in the output block, and use `mutate` to drop the fields you don't want in the audit index.